# jQuery .bind or .on wont bing to new record

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button to create a new record in a div and a close button beside each record to remove them.

The remove button will remove the records that load with the page. But does not work with the new .append records.

I cannot see why the .click event will not bind to the new records.

Here is a jsFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/ukkpower/kqxsL/1/

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: there is no javascript in your fiddle

Comment: There is no JavaScript in your fiddle and you selected Mootools instead of jQuery. Please provide a more complete fiddle. You are probably using `.on` incorrectly, the documentation describes very well though how event delegation works (section **Direct and delegated events**): http://api.jquery.com/on/.

Comment: my jsFiddle is set to jQuery 1.7.2. The reason I have tagged javascript as it may be solution to my answer and may not be a jQuery issue. I am not sure.

Comment: The fiddle link is WRONG http://jsfiddle.net/ukkpower/kqxsL/1/, updated above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click','.cart-popup__del',function()
{
    $(this).closest('.cart-popup__list-wrap').remove();

    return false;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kqxsL/3/)**

Comment: thanks that worked, was unsure of using the $(document), I thought I had to place the name of the element instead

Comment: @KeithPower this attaches the event to the document object. When a click event bubbles up to the document, jQuery checks to see if the event originated from the matched element `'.cart-popup__del'`. If it does, it calls that function.

Comment: @Keith: The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is quite good. I recommend to the take the time, read it and have a look at the examples. It will save you a lot of time eventually.

Comment: Thanks Felix. I have read the best part of it, but because it is still relatively new to me, it all sounded a bit fuzzy. The advice here has given more insight so I think I will go back over it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `.click` event for dynamically added content, use `.on` instead, it's a [live event](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("recordWrapper").on("click","#closeButton",function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".cart-popup__list-wrap").on('click',".cart-popup__del", function() {
```